# Is it possible to selectively disable jquery ui selectable behavior on dynamically created elements?

Tags: jquery

I want to accomplish this:

```
$('li.activerun').live(selectable({disabled: true});
```

or

```
$('li.activerun').live('selectable', {disabled: true}, someFunction);
```

I know that syntax is wrong and will not run, but I want to be able to perform the equivalent and am wondering if this is possible. I am adding the .activerun class dynamically to certain list elements based on the results of an ajax submission, thus the live function. I want all list elements that have the class .activerun to be ineligible for selection via selectable().

Is it possible? How to disable selectable() on future elements?

Or is it possible to use the filter option of selectable() to narrow down the range of elements that are able to be selected?

```
$( ".selector" ).selectable({ filter: not .activerow });
```

How would I use filter in this situation to make all elements that are not of class activerow selectable (in the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cross browser support for an event on [dom mutation events](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html#t10).  To achieve what you are looking for you could use the [`.livequery()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin.

> Live Query also has the ability to
>   fire a function (callback) when it
>   matches a new element and another
>   function (callback) for when an
>   element is no longer matched. This
>   provides ultimate flexibility and
>   untold use-cases. For example the
>   following code uses a function based
>   Live Query to implement the jQuery
>   hover helper method and remove it when
>   the element is no longer matched.

So you would end up with something like this:

```
$('li.activerun').livequery(function(){
   //do some function
});
```

Without the use of a plugin you could also look at [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) to see if there are any new `li.activerun` elements.